# Submit Successful VF Page after Save Button Clicked

Tags: visualforce

Currently, when 'Save' is selected, SF directs to the new record. As our form will be filled out by external guests without a login, we want to be able to direct to another VF page that states 'Your submission was successful' when the form is saved. I do not want a pop-up message/alert here.

My controller is named Intake__c.
My main VF page is named Intake.
My secondary VP page I want to direct to on save is named Congratulations.

I know I'll need to create a controller extension, but I'm having trouble with what to put there for the redirect to function properly. It also looks like an extension is created by creating a new Apex Class in the Developer Console and referencing in the  tag on the VF page - Is this correct? SF's notes werern't super clear here.

Here is my VF page code currently;

```
<apex:page standardController="Intake__c" standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    
  
  <link REL="Favicon" HREF="{!URLFOR($Resource.favicon)}"/>  
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.styleForIntake}"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   
  
  
<body>
<!-- multistep form -->
<apex:form Id="msform" styleClass="form">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <br></br><br></br>
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Client Info</li>
    <li>Residence </li>
    <li>Tech Recom.</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
 <br></br><br></br>
   <fieldset>
   <br></br><br></br>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Client Information</h2> 
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Here, we will gather information specific to the client.</h3> <br></br>
    <p>  
        Client Name (First and Last Initial): <br></br> 
     </p>
        <apex:inputField styleClass="fieldset" label="Client Name (First and Last Intial):" value="{!Intake__c.Client_Name_First_and_Last_Initial__c}"/> 
    <br></br> <br></br>
     <p>  
        Client Preferred Pronouns: <br></br> 
     </p>
    <div class="pronoun">
        <apex:inputField styleClass="fieldset" value="{!Intake__c.Preferred_Pronouns__c}"/>
    </div>
    <br></br> <br></br>
     <p>  
        Client Communicates With (Select all that Apply):
     </p>
    <div class="selectiondiv">
        <apex:inputField styleClass="fieldset" value="{!Intake__c.This_Person_Communicates_With__c}"/>
    </div>
    <br></br> <br></br>
    
   
    <br></br> <br></br><br></br> <br></br>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset >
    
    
   <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Residence Information</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Here we will ask for information on the residence where the technology will be used.</h3>
    <br></br> <br></br>

    <p>  
        Type of Residence: <br></br> 
    </p>
     <div class="selectiondiv">
        <apex:inputField styleClass="fieldset" value="{!Intake__c.Residence_Type__c}">
        </apex:inputField>
     </div>
    
    
    <br></br> <br></br><br></br> <br></br>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
          
  
      <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Technology Recommendation</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Based on your selections for 'Concerns Addressed', we recommend the following technology:</h3>
           
           <apex:pageblock id="seizures">
               <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Intake__c.Population__c, 'Epilepsy/Seizures'), 'true', 'false')}" value="SimplyHome does not currently support Epilepsy/Seizure-detecting technology. However, we may be able to asssist with additionally noted concerns."/>
           </apex:pageblock>
           
           <apex:pageblock id="technologyRecommendation">
           
           
            <apex:pageblockSection >
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(!CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c,"Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom"), "true", "false")}" value="    SimplyHome System"/>
          </apex:pageblockSection>
          
      
        </apex:pageblock>
    <br></br> <br></br><br></br> <br></br>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />

    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" styleClass="submit action-button" style="width=100px" value="Submit" id="saveButton" />
     </fieldset>
     
     
     <fieldset>
           <p> Thank you for your submission </p>
           
     </fieldset> 
    
 
</apex:form>

<script>
//jQuery time




var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; 
var left, opacity, scale; 
var animating; 





$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
    
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
    
    next_fs.show(); 
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'
      });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
    
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
    
    previous_fs.show(); 
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
     
    });
});




$(document).ready(function () {
$("#datepicker2").datepicker({
dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
yearRange: "-100:+0"
});

});


$(document).ready(function () {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
yearRange: "-100:+0"
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a controller extension and called it within my VF page.

The header became :

```
<apex:page standardController="Intake__c" extensions="IntakeExtension" standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
```

and I created an Apex Class to be an extension of Intake that looks like this:

```
public with sharing class IntakeExtension {
    public IntakeExtension(ApexPages.StandardController Intake) {
    }
    public PageReference save() {
        return Page.Congratulations;
    }
}
```